# What kind of algorithm generates permutations of sets as well as their elements in C#?

Tags: c#, algorithm, recursion, permutation

I've spent the last few days thinking about how to solve this but i'm just not sure on how. Say i have two sets A and B with different elements but the same cardinality merged into set S. S can be S<sub>1</sub> = {A1, B1}, S<sub>2</sub> = {A1, A2, B1, B2}, S<sub>3</sub> = {A1, A2, A3, B1, B2, B3} and so on.
How can i generate a list of elements where the permutation happens on two levels. First each set, A and B in this case, is permutated. Then each element inside A and B is permutated. Could such an algorithm also deal with more sets than just A and B?

Output for S<sub>1</sub>:

```
{A1, B1}  {B1, A1}
```

Output for S<sub>2</sub>:

```
{A1, B1, B2, A2}  {A2, B1, B2, A1}  
{A1, B2, B1, A2}  {A2, B2, B1, A1}  
{B1, A1, A2, B2}  {B2, A1, A2, B1}  
{B1, A2, A1, B2}  {B2, A2, A1, B1}
```

To not fill the whole page i've typed only half of the output for S<sub>3</sub>.
The missing half will have an element from B as the first element and an element from A as the last element in each list.

```
{A1, B1, B2, A2, A3, B3}  {A1, B1, B2, A3, A2, B3}   
{A1, B2, B1, A2, A3, B3}  {A1, B2, B1, A3, A2, B3}  
{A1, B2, B3, A2, A3, B1}  {A1, B2, B3, A3, A2, B1}  
{A1, B3, B2, A2, A3, B1}  {A1, B3, B2, A3, A2, B1}  
{A1, B3, B1, A2, A3, B2}  {A1, B3, B1, A3, A2, B2}  
{A1, B1, B3, A2, A3, B2}  {A1, B1, B3, A3, A2, B2}  

{A2, B1, B2, A1, A3, B3}  {A2, B1, B2, A3, A1, B3}   
{A2, B2, B1, A1, A3, B3}  {A2, B2, B1, A3, A1, B3}   
{A2, B2, B3, A1, A3, B1}  {A2, B2, B3, A3, A1, B1}   
{A2, B3, B2, A1, A3, B1}  {A2, B3, B2, A3, A1, B1}   
{A2, B3, B1, A1, A3, B2}  {A2, B3, B1, A3, A1, B2}    
{A2, B1, B3, A1, A3, B2}  {A2, B1, B3, A3, A1, B2}  

{A3, B1, B2, A1, A2, B3}  {A3, B1, B2, A2, A1, B3}   
{A3, B2, B1, A1, A2, B3}  {A3, B2, B1, A2, A1, B3}   
{A3, B2, B3, A1, A2, B1}  {A3, B2, B3, A2, A1, B1}   
{A3, B3, B2, A1, A2, B1}  {A3, B3, B2, A2, A1, B1}   
{A3, B3, B1, A1, A2, B2}  {A3, B3, B1, A2, A1, B2}   
{A3, B1, B3, A1, A2, B2}  {A3, B1, B3, A2, A1, B2}
```

Here's what i have to generate a normal permutation for a list of objects, but how would i adapt this for this specific problem?

```cs
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Permute<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence)
{
    if (sequence == null)
    {
        yield break;
    }

    var list = sequence.ToList();

    if (!list.Any())
    {
        yield return Enumerable.Empty<T>();
    }
    else
    {
        var startingElementIndex = 0;

        foreach (var startingElement in list)
        {
            var remainingItems = list.AllExcept(startingElementIndex);

            foreach (var permutationOfRemainder in remainingItems.Permute())
            {
                yield return startingElement.Concat(permutationOfRemainder);
            }

            startingElementIndex++;
        }
    }
}

private static IEnumerable<T> Concat<T>(this T firstElement, IEnumerable<T> secondSequence)
{
    yield return firstElement;
    if (secondSequence == null)
    {
        yield break;
    }

    foreach (var item in secondSequence)
    {
        yield return item;
    }
}

private static IEnumerable<T> AllExcept<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence, int indexToSkip)
{
    if (sequence == null)
    {
        yield break;
    }

    var index = 0;

    foreach (var item in sequence.Where(item => index++ != indexToSkip))
    {
        yield return item;
    }
}
```

Comment: As you got more then 2 elements in each permutation, you ahve to use Recursion. This might be a "hard recursive" problem that can not be solved via a loop, only via recursion. If nothing else, writing recursion will be easier then having 5 nested for loops.

Comment: In the output for `S2` why isn't `{A1, A2, B1, B2}` one of the items?